# Reputation linkage between main site and meta ?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Is there some linkage in reputation between the meta site and the parent site ? my meta.tex rep is tracking my site rep, without any apparent new activity in meta. I actually like this, but haven't seen this behavior on meta.SO and SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your reputation on meta is the same as your reputation on the normal site- it is updated every hour.

Complete information is [contained in the FAQ](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

see

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Also the [faq on this very site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/faq).