# Discrepancy between chat and main reputation

Tags: support, reputation, chat

A recent question - [Reputation linkage between main site and meta?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/5764) - regarding the linkage between reputation on [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com) and [main](http://tex.stackexchange.com) mentions a discrepancy that is resolved every hour on the meta-side.

However, there also exists a discrepancy on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) that I cannot resolve. Consider, for example, [my reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) on the main site:

[image: Reputation on main site]

Now, compared this to the reputation posted on chat:

[image]

Where does that difference of 320 come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On [chat.se](http://chat.stackexchange.com), the reputation shown is the sum of your reputation across the network.

*Note that chat also syncs your account information hourly, so there can also be a bit of a cache discrepancy there.