# Reputation stats not showing correctly in chat

Tags: support, bug, chat

The left most screen shows a user's reputation, the middle screen shows my reputation, and the rightmost screen shows the reputation stats displayed in the chat. The numbers seem awfully off - just before when I was in chat it once displayed my reputation as 307 and in the message after as 319.

What maybe causing the bug?

- Mozilla Firefox 93
- Windows 7
- URLs of the pages: leftmost - user page of the user, middle - user page of me, rightmost - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130453/discussion-between-vscode-fanboy-and-marijn

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chat system is network wide, rather than being site-specific. As such, the reputation you see in chat is the overall value for all network sites.

Comment: So the chat system gets all user/identifydata as the network-wide but gives us the LaTeX site-colours and stuff?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy The rooms get some styling based on their linked site, yes. You can see the chat system is network wide if for example something gets flagged: all moderators across the entire network can act on such flags.

Comment: Thanks for answering quick and responding as well as providing great info. +1 What about this: _ just before when I was in chat it once displayed my reputation as 307 and in the message after as 319._ ?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy The two systems are not tightly bound: data gets synced from the main sites to the chat system - I think there's a meta question somewhere about the 'lag'.

Comment: Can you post the meta question - yes i know there are synced not one big database :).

Comment: And I recently read a "talk in chat privilege" article on super use I think and it said about the sum of the all reputation.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy I think  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/discrepancy-between-chat-and-main-reputation was in my mind

Comment: I will read it.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy "gets all user/identifydata as the network-wide" -- actually it is a bit more complicated. Things like the displayed user name, information about a possible suspension etc. gets inherited from the parent site of your chat account. That's not necessarily tex.se, you can set it to any site which is on the chat server you want to use.